# Python - List comprehension expression for assigning values from list to list of DataFrames

Tags: python, list, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a list of `DataFrame` (one per file I have read in)  and a list of strings (the filenames of the files). I want to create a new column `filename` in each `DataFrame` and assign it the corresponding value in the file name list. The goal is to identify the source of the data once I have concatenated the `DataFrame` list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
                     'B' : 'bar',
                     'C' : 'foo' })

list_df = [df,df,df]
file_names = ['source1','source2','source3']
```

I am trying to do something like so:

```
[x.loc[:,'filename']  = file for (x,file) in (list_df,file_names)]
```

This is obviously not working as iterating over a tuple is not allowed within a list comprehension expression(?). For loop would be an option (but sub-optimal). Is it possible to achieve this using list comprehension and is that the most efficient solution?

Comment: List comprehensions are a functional programming tool, don't use them to intentionally create side-effects. What is "sub-optimal" about a `for` loop that avoids pointlessly creating a list that is probably just populated with `None`, only to immediately collect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct method to do this would be a simple for loop using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function , Example -

```
for df_,file in zip(list_df,file_names):
    df_.loc[:,'filename'] = file
```

---

But if you really must use list comprehension, you cannot use assignment statements inside a list comprehension. Instead of that, you can try creating a function that does the assignment, and call that function using list comprehension.

You would also need to [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the list of dataframes and `file_names` list together, to get the elements at their corresponding indexes together.

Example -

```
def func(df,file):
    df.loc[:,'filename'] = file

[func(df_,file) for df_,file in zip(list_df,file_names)]
```

Demo -

```
In [54]: df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
   ....:                      'B' : 'bar',
   ....:                      'C' : 'foo' })

In [55]: list_df = [df,df,df]

In [56]: file_names = ['source1','source2','source3']

In [57]: def func(df,file):
   ....:     df.loc[:,'filename'] = file
   ....:

In [58]: [func(df,file) for df,file in zip(list_df,file_names)]
Out[58]: [None, None, None]

In [59]: df
Out[59]:
   A    B    C filename
0  1  bar  foo  source3
1  1  bar  foo  source3
2  1  bar  foo  source3
3  1  bar  foo  source3
```

Comment: Ok fair, I have added that as well.